# Put environment in prod and remove the profiler Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am putting my website in production, but I have a problem with the environment.As you can see in the screenshot below, the site remains in "dev" mode

[image]

However, I already modify my .env file as follows:

```
APP_ENV=prod
APP_DEBUG=0
APP_SECRET=secretthings
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
#TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost,example.com
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###
```

should I change another file or do something else so that my site is finally operational?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Can you share more details?

Comment: Especially details about the production server.  In most cases, the .env files are not used in production.  In fact, the Dotenv class which parses the .env files is not even installed on a production only system.

Comment: @Cerad I have it installed and running on multiple different projects on production systems

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clear your cache?
Move to your project and type `php bin/console cache:clear`. You can also pass the enviroment you want to clear with `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`. Use `dev` or `prod` as your parameter.

Edit: If you have a `.env.local` file - you need to change your enviroment there.

Answer (score -2):

After you update your `.env` file you should run `composer dump-env prod` to compile your environment file for production use.

Comment: Please explain further why that should be needed. `.env` is also read and processed in prod mode

Comment: If you open any .env file generated when developing, you will see this line added there.

Comment: Yes, I see that line. But that's only a performance improvement. Everything should work the same way